# Haskell: eval :: Ast -> Int

Tags: haskell, eval

I have an assignment, and there's one question that I just do not understand. What is it that they're asking for? Not sure if this is a SO-fitted question, but I'm in a complete brain freeze, so it would mean a lot if anyone helped!

Question:

Let's consider user-defined data type
data Ast = V Int | P Ast Ast | M Ast Ast
We imagine that each leaf V x represents the number x, while P and M represent
addition and multiplication of their arguments. Program a function

```
eval :: Ast -> Int
```

which evaluates such an Ast as an arithmetic expression, e.g.

```
eval (V 5) = 5
eval (P (V 55) (M (V 2) (V 3))) = 55 + (2 * 3) = 61
eval (M (P (V 12) (V 3)) (M (V 2) (V 5))) = (12 + 3) * (2 * 5) = 150
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nice thing with a language like Haskell is, definitions actually look almost like examples. The ones you gave form literally a syntactically valid definition:

```
eval :: Ast -> Int
eval (V 5) = 5
eval (P (V 55) (M (V 2) (V 3))) = 55 + (2 * 3)
eval (M (P (V 12) (V 3)) (M (V 2) (V 5))) = (12 + 3) * (2 * 5)
```

Only, it is neither minimal nor complete. For instance, `eval (V 5)` will be ok, but `eval (V 6)` won't. Solution? Well, don't hard-code the particular case of `5`, but instead allow any int value:

```
eval (V x) = x
```

Likewise, you should make clauses that match *anything* of the form of a sum / product, respectively, not just one particular example expression.

```
eval (P l r) = _ + _
```

To fill in the gaps, you'll need already-evaluated expressions corresponding to `l` and `r`. Well, `l` and `r` are not evaluated... if only we had a function that takes expressions and gives us their evaluated form...